# ActiveMQ redelivery does not work

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, dead-letter

I am trying the implement a dead letter queue using ActiveMQ. Unfortunately the documentation on this end is rather vague on some aspects and I can't seem to get everything properly set up.

I have the following Beans configured:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate createJMSTemplate() {
    logger.info("createJMSTemplate");
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(getActiveMQConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(queue);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(getActiveMQConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("1-10");
    factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory getActiveMQConnectionFactory() {
    // Configure the ActiveMQConnectionFactory
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("com.company"));

    // Configure the redeliver policy and the dead letter queue
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(0);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(10000);
    redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(3);
    RedeliveryPolicyMap redeliveryPolicyMap = activeMQConnectionFactory.getRedeliveryPolicyMap();
    redeliveryPolicyMap.put(new ActiveMQQueue(queue), redeliveryPolicy);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);

    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}
```

And this is my receiving code:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueReceiver.class);
private Connection connection;
private Session session;
private SegmentReceiver callback;

@PostConstruct
private void init() throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Initializing QueueReceiver...");
    this.connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    this.session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue q = session.createQueue(queue);
    logger.info("Creating consumer for queue '{}'", q.getQueueName());
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(q);
    this.callback = new SegmentReceiver();
    consumer.setMessageListener(callback);
    this.connection.start();
}

@PreDestroy
private void destroy() throws JMSException {
    logger.info("Destroying QueueReceiver...");
    this.session.close();
    this.connection.close();
}

private class SegmentReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        logger.info("onMessage");
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            Segment segment = Segment.fromJSON(textMessage.getText());
            if (segment.shouldFail()) {
                throw new IOException("This segment is expected to fail");
            }
            System.out.println(segment.getText());
            message.acknowledge();
        }
        catch(IOException | JMSException exception) {
            logger.error(exception.toString());
            try {
                QueueReceiver.this.session.rollback();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

However, nothing happens. I am using an out-of-the-box Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.2 setup using the default configuration. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are using 
`this.session = connection.createSession(false,Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);`
calling `message.acknowledge();` is the same than calling `session.acknowledge();` .

to have ActiveMQ redelivery working successfully with your config, there is some possibilities with minimal changes:

1. calling `QueueReceiver.this.session.recover();`
   in place of calling   `QueueReceiver.this.session.rollback();`

> void org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.recover() throws JMSException
>
> Stops message delivery in this session, and restarts message delivery
>   with the oldest unacknowledged message.
>
> All consumers deliver messages in a serial order. Acknowledging a
>   received message automatically acknowledges all messages that have
>   been delivered to the client.
>
> Restarting a session causes it to take the following actions:  •Stop
>   message delivery  •Mark all messages that might have been delivered
>   but not acknowledged as "redelivered"  •Restart the delivery sequence
>   including all unacknowledged messages that had been previously
>   delivered. Redelivered messages do not have to be delivered in exactly
>   their original delivery order.

2. use 
   `this.session = connection.createSession(false, org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE);` 
   and call 
   `((org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage) message ).acknowledge();` , note that not calling this method is like a rollback, means the message is not acknowledged and throwing an exception in `onMessage` method will call `QueueReceiver.this.consumer.rollback();` of **org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.rollback()**.
3. simply calling `QueueReceiver.this.consumer.rollback();` **org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.rollback()** in place of calling `QueueReceiver.this.session.rollback();`

Comment: I seem to be having some success with creating the session with ```ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE``` and ```this.session.rollback()```. Messages are only added to the DLQ when the application is stopped though, it seems to retry to messages infinite times rather than the 3 redeliveries that I've configured.

Answer (score 0):

So it proved to be a combination of issues:

- The session acknowledge mode needed to be set to `ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE`
- I'm using `session.recover()` rather than `rollback()`
- The ActiveMQ broker wasn't properly configured. I needed to add this bit to the activemq.xml configuration file (place it under the `<broker>` tag).

  ```
      <destinationPolicy>
      <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
          <policyEntry topic=">" >
              <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                   slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                   by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                   For more information, see:

                   http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

              -->
            <pendingMessageLimitStrategy> 
              <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
            </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
          </policyEntry>
          <!-- Set the following policy on all queues using the '>' wildcard -->
          <policyEntry queue=">">
              <deadLetterStrategy>
                  <!--
                    Use the prefix 'DLQ.' for the destination name, and make
                    the DLQ a queue rather than a topic
                  -->
                  <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ." useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
              </deadLetterStrategy>
          </policyEntry>
        </policyEntries>
      </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>
  ```
- Make sure you didn't active any `redeliveryPlugin` that can mess with your ActiveMQConnectionFactory configuration.